# How to update a component in one window from another window in Netbeans Platform?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, platform

I'm fairly new to Netbeans Platform. Here is what I'm trying to do, I have two windows, one is the main window which is 'editor' and the second one is an 'explorer' window with a JTree component in it. Every time I add a new Item to my database, I want to add a node to the JTree component in explorer window ! I was trying to find a way to call an updater method from the main window, but so far no luck ! both windows are located in the same module and the same package ! is there a way I can do that ?

Comment: I use NetBeans lots, but forgive me I do not get what is your problem. Could you please clarify it. Maybe use a clearer example/image?

Comment: Btw I forgot to say that I'm writing a Java Desktop application using Netbeans platform. ok, here is an example .. in netbeans IDE itself, when you write a new function in your code immediately the function name appears on the Navigator window which is a separate window than your Editor window that means your editor window is passing a message to calling a method from the Navigator windows in order to perform that update. i'm trying to do the same thing ! but I can't access one window from another one.

Comment: So you want to write a NetBeans plugin/extension? I think there might be a way of installing PropertyChangeListeners on those windows or something like that. Sorry I will not help much here, but +1 as I am interested in the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In NetBeans Platform applications you use the Lookup API do communicate between TopComponents/ modules.

http://netbeans.dzone.com/news/top-10-netbeans-apis-part-2

http://netbeans.org/kb/trails/platform.html

I also recommend to read a NetBeans Platform book to get the basics.